# Netbeans 8.0 - Preferences for code folding

Tags: netbeans, code-folding

I have recently switched to using Netbeans IDE 8.0 for a PHP project and would like to know if it's possible to either:-

1. Configure NetBeans to remember my code fold status (open/ closed) when I save the file
2. Automatically fold only functions upon startup.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Phill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Netbeans cannot remember the state (see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188573).

Regarding your second question have a look at: Tools / Options / Folding.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I wasn't aware of the bug reporting part of netbeans website. I will keep an eye out.